# How to check status when commandFinished() signal is emitted

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm trying to create a ftp client for multiple user accounts. While adding a user account, I need to check whether the host and user details are valid or not. For that I created a method.

```
bool FtpConnect::checkConnectivity(QString remoteIP, QString username, QString password)
{
    QUrl server;
    server.setScheme("ftp");
    server.setHost(remoteIP);
    if (!server.isValid()) {
        QMessageBox::warning(0, "Error", "Invalid Host");
        return false;
    }
    server.setPort(21);
    server.setUserName(username);
    server.setPassword(password);
    QFtp *ftp = new QFtp(this);
    ftp->connectToHost(server.host(), server.port());
    int status = ftp->login(server.userName(), server.password());
    QMessageBox::information(0, "Updated", QString::number(status));
    return (ftp->list() == 4) ? true : false;
}
```

I need the code to return true if the connection is ok and false while the connection could not complete. Noe the variable `status` returns `4` which is the `QFtp::Connecting` signal. please somebody help me.

Comment: I have not used QFtp, so i may be wrong here. I did not understand why you are using 'return (ftp->list() == 4)' instead, can't you use 'state()' function?(return (ftp->state() ==4) which returns the current state of the object

Comment: but it returns zero always. not the current status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QFtp methods do not block execution. The command is scheduled, and its execution is performed asynchronously.
You can't check `status()` right after you call `connectToHost()` or `login()`, because at this moment state is still `Unconnected`. You should wait for a signal to be emitted instead.
`ftp->list()` and other methods return the command id, so there's no point in checking return values. What you can do is remember the id and wait for `commandFinished()` signal with this id, but there is another option.
Use [QFtp::stateChanged](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qftp.html#stateChanged) and check for `QFtp::LoggedIn`.

Comment: Can it be done something like this - while(ftp->hasPendingCommands ()) continue; and then check the state()?

Comment: QFtp works with the event loop on the owner thread (where it was created, by default), so if we block the thread with a while loop nothing will happen. But we can use an in-place QEventLoop to do something similar